# Faraday's law applied to self inductance

Tags: electromagnetism

Does Faraday's law permit to establish curl ( non zero) in a loop when magnetic flux lines are fully conserved(zero leakage) via a n ideal magnetic circuit?[image: explanation diagram]

can I introduce a potential gradient at point P and change surface current?

Answer (score 0):

The process by which Faraday's law establishes a curl is the reduction of the loop being considered to infinitesimal dimensions, or taking the limit. If the fields are sufficiently smooth, then the curl can be expressed in terms of derivatives in the standard manner. In an ideal magnetic material with zero leakage, the magnetic field drops to zero suddenly at the boundary, with perhaps ambiguity as to its value right on the boundary. This can mean a discontinuity in the curl of the electric field which is proportional to the rate of change in the magnetic field, by Maxwell's equations. This type of configuration can lead to impulsive fields or currents or charges. This is sometimes referred to as a sheet of charge, for example. For any loop that does not cross the boundary, there is no problem. For loops that cross the boundary, the integral form of Maxwell's equations, or the theory of distributions, or some analysis using the impulse function is required.

So, the curl is established by Faraday's law in this context, however there are mathematical technical details involved when the properties of the materials are discontinuous, as suggested by the use of bounded ideal magnetic material.

(If these details are not attended to with care, incorrect conclusions can be easily made. One good rule for this is to consider a continuous approximation to the discontinuity, such as making the magnetic field change very rapidly instead of discontinuously, and checking qualitatively what would happen.)

Comment: I have simplified my query with diagram now.

Comment: So you have a uniform sheet of electric current circulating the circular axis of a torus? In that case the magnetic field is confined even without ideal magnetic material. Also, the electric field required in this case is zero. So, if your question is about the electric (scalar) potential - an applied constant electric field complicates the details, especially if it affects the current flow, but is not directly interacting with the magnetic field. Is this the topic of the question?

Comment: yes almost that is my query @Ponder Stibbons. I understand in that case electric field is not required for charges to flow. but still if a constant field is applied in the direction of flow it is supposed to cause an acceleration to the charges . that will keep on increasing the surface current. my interest is in knowledge of subsequent magnetic field and induced emf what we call self inductance in popular sense?